# PSQL enforce uniqueness, but within a subset of a table, not through the entire thing

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema, unique

I'm creating a database of assessments for courses using PostgreSQL.

I'd like assessment names to be unique within the course, but two courses can have assessments with the same name.

```
-- assessment contains the different assignments & labs that
-- students may submit their code to.
CREATE TABLE assessment (
    id           SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name         VARCHAR(255)    UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    comments     TEXT            NOT NULL,
    type         ASSESSMENT_TYPE NOT NULL,
    course_id    SERIAL          NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES courses(id)
);

-- courses contains the information about a course. Since
-- the same course can run multiple times, a single course
-- is uniquely identified by (course_code, year, period)
CREATE TABLE courses (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name        VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL, -- Unique within all courses. Wrong!
    course_code VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
    period      PERIOD       NOT NULL,
    year        INTEGER      NOT NULL
);
```

Two main points:

1. Can I do this without changing the schema?
2. If so, is there a more idiomatic solution that may include schema changes?

Comment: If a course is uniquely identified by (course_code, year, period), that that should be a unique constraint.

Comment: `assessment.course_id` should **not** be a `serial`, but a normal `integer` column.

Comment: This is not clear. Did you comment name in the wrong table? You say you want a certain uniqueness of "assessment names". Is name in courses the name of a course or of an assessment? And is name in assessment the name of an assessment or of a course? Are courses name values also assesment table name values? Are assessment table name values also courses name values? Please clearly describe what a row says when in a table & what the restrictions on possible database states are. PS Time to read a textbook on information modeling & database design, including normalization to higher NFs.

Comment: Your "courses" table is really an "offering" table--where one registers for & attends & assesses an offering of a course--which should be suggested by course_code not being PK/UNIQUE in it. You are confusingly overloading "course". (Your design probably overloads "name" in a non-confusing way. But we can't tell until you give clear table meanings & constraints.)

Comment: Also when you say "course" in "assessment names to be unique within the course, but two courses can have assessments with the same name" it's not clear what table you mean or whether you mean unique within courses id or course_code or even some (assesment id, course) pair (whichever of the previous two senses of "course" applies).

Comment: PostgreSQL does not have a type `PERIOD`. Did you create a custom type here? If so, why not simply use `tsrange` or `tstzrange` instead? Then you could omit the `year` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. Can I do this without changing the schema?

No, since you have multiple issues here.

1. Your assessments are globally unique by name and not within a course.
2. `assessment.course_id` has its own sequence which is useless (`SERIAL` is just `INTEGER` + `SEQUENCE`)
3. Table `courses` defines a column data type that does not exist: `PERIOD` (at least not up to version 11)

### 2. If so, is there a more idiomatic solution that may include schema changes?

A modified schema that should do what you want would look like this following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE courses (
    id          SERIAL       PRIMARY KEY,
    name        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    course_code VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
    period      tstzrange    NOT NULL
);

-- the following is required to build the proper unique constraint...
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS btree_gist;

-- the unique constraint: no two courses with same name at any point in time
ALTER TABLE courses
    ADD CONSTRAINT idx_unique_courses
    EXCLUDE USING GIST (name WITH =, period WITH &&);

CREATE TABLE assessment (
    id           SERIAL          PRIMARY KEY,
    name         VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
    comments     TEXT            NOT NULL,
    type         ASSESSMENT_TYPE NOT NULL,
    course_id    INTEGER         NOT NULL REFERENCES courses(id),
    UNIQUE (course_id, name)
);
```